# print multiple highcharts chart

Tags: javascript, php, highcharts

I am using `highcharts.js` and have a book that I print a bunch of the graphs and have hole punched and available for others to see (I know, weird - I am using paper...)

Anyway, right now I have to manually open up each graph and use the `export` option to individual print these graphs.

I have a plain-white background webpage and based on the `$_GET` parameters, it dynamically displays the graph.

Ideally I could create a PHP script that could loop through the graphs I need in order to send multiple to print at once.

The only problem seems to be that you have to manually click the `export` button each time, which of course I cannot progamatically do this.

If the function that prints it were known, I could invoke the function - but I am not expert in this library.

Does anybody have any work-arounds for this?

Thank you.

**EDIT:**

Based on @Halver link, I put the following into my script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(e) {
        var myChart = $("#graph").highcharts();
        myChart.print();
    });
 </script>
```

I put this in the header.

However now I am getting an error in my console saying:

`typeError: myChart is not defined`

Any idea how I can fix this?

Comment: @HalvorStrand - Tried that.... Got a undefined function error...

Comment: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Chart.print

Comment: @HalvorStrand - I updated my question based on this comment. Could you give me any answer on this? Tku!

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can programatically click export.. Modify the highcharts page like so:

Change

```
<body>
```

to:

```
<body onload="document.getElementById('exportButtonID').click();">
```

..you will have to find the id of the export button, or assign one.  Without more info it's hard to offer automation advice.